# How to compile and install this source without errors? Link in the description

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compile, configure

It's very important for me to install QCADesigner 2.0.3 on my linux system (Ubuntu 16.04). You can find the source [here](http://www.mina.ubc.ca/qcadesigner_downloads). When I tried to configure it by running ./autogen.sh as mentioned in the readme file, I got the following error:

```
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
src/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
+ glib-gettextize -c
Copying file po/Makefile.in.in


Please add the files
  codeset.m4 gettext.m4 glibc21.m4 iconv.m4 isc-posix.m4 lcmessage.m4
  progtest.m4
from the /usr/share/aclocal directory to your autoconf macro directory
or directly to your aclocal.m4 file.
You will also need config.guess and config.sub, which you can get from
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/config/.
```

But there isn't mentioned file (config.sub, config.guess) in the given link. Please someone help me to install this software.

**Update:** I've got the files config.sub and config.guess. But I have the following questions.

1) I don't have `isc-posix.m4` in my `/usr/share/aclocal` directory. But I have `printf-posix.m4` (I don't know if they're same). I have all other `.m4` files. Where should I find `isc-posix.m4`?

2) Which is 'autoconf macro directory' ? OR

3) How to copy the above files to `aclocal.m4` file?

4) Where should I put `config.guess` and `config.sub` files into?

Answer (score 0):

If you go the mentioned [URL](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/config/) you would find a [README](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/config/README) that contains the [new location](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=summary) of both files. As the links might change I'm not including the links themselves.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. Please see if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that the aclocal.m4 file included with the source was generated with a different version of automake, or the paths were different on the original build system.

Either way, you can generate a new `aclocal.m4` file with the `autoreconf` utility, which will point to the locations of those missing .m4 files.

```
$ cp aclocal.m4 aclocal.m4.bak # Back up the original just in case
$ autoreconf -ivf
```

You can then run your `./autogen.sh`, and it should pick up the paths to the .m4 files.